# How to set background color of a column in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

```
 <staticText>
       <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="25" backcolor="#A6A6A6" />
                <box>

                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>

                </box>
      <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>

     <text><![CDATA[Nom]]></text>
</staticText>
```

I need to change the background color, i tried the attribute " backcolor="#A6A6A6" " but it it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `mode="Opaque"`.